# How to get one single key-value pair as output from reducer

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I am new to Hadoop Mapreduce. I have a requirement where lets say I want to find the student name with highest mark. Consider the sample dataset

Harry   Maths      80

Harry   Physics    67

Daisy   Science    89

Daisy   Physics    90

Greg    Maths      70

Greg    Chemistry  79

I know that reducer iterates over each of the unique key, hence I am going to get 3 output key value pairs with name and total marks. But I need the **name of the student with the total highest mark** ie. **Reducer output -> Daisy    179**

Following is the reduce function I have written :

```
 static int maxMark = 0;
 static Text name = new Text();
 public static class Reduce extends MapReduceBase implements
        Reducer<Text, IntWritable, Text, IntWritable> {

    public void reduce(Text key, Iterator<IntWritable> values, 
    OutputCollector<Text, IntWritable> output, Reporter reporter) throws IOException{
   int totalMarks = 0;
   while(values.hasNext())
   {
      totalMarks+=values.next().get();
   }    
   if (totalMarks > maxMark){
      maxMark = totalMarks;
      name = key;
          output.collect(name, new IntWritable(maxMark));
   }
```

}

But this logic is going to output the previously saved student's name and mark as well!
I can solve this problem if I know the number of input keys to the reducer before the reducer is even called, so that when the reducer iterates over the last key (name), I can call **output.collect(name, new IntWritable(maxMark));** once..

So, is there a way to find the number of input keys to the reducer? Or else, what are the other alternatives to get one single output from reducer?

Answer (score 2):

You need two map reduce jobs.  The first will total up the marks by name, irrespective of group.  Then you can run a job with a mapper that turns the keys and values around, so the key is the sum of marks from the previous step, making sure to use a descending comparator.  Configure this job to use only a single reducer task and it can flag itself to ignore all but the first call to reduce.

Comment: I am fine with the first part. Could you please elaborate on the second part where 1st reducer's output is interchanged to input the 2nd Map Reduce job and how this can be achieved..?

Comment: What's the question?  You are in charge of where the first job's reducer's output goes, so just point your second job at that location.